# Trouble filtering out all former muncipality's in the Netherlands that have an end time

Tags: filter, sparql, wikidata

I am currently doing an exercise in which i am asked the following question:

"Return the name of all Dutch municipalities and its number of inhabitants ordered by the number of inhabitants"

So after trying for a while I think i had the right solution, but my query will not filter out municipalities with an end time.

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT ?muncipality (MAX(?population) AS ?maxPopulation)
WHERE
{
  ?muncipality wdt:P31 wd:Q2039348;
               wdt:P1082 ?population.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{?muncipality wdt:P582 ?endtime}
}
GROUP BY ?muncipality
ORDER BY DESC(?maxPopulation)
```

I have added a picture of a muncipality with an end date that I can not filter for reference.
[Muncipality which I can't filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKziT.png)

I have tried the above code and have looked for ways to filter on end time, but with no success. I have also tried to filter using wdt:P576 (dissolved, abolished or demolished date), which filtered out more than my original query, but there are still a lot of muncipalities with an end time but no dissolved, abolished or demolished date.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: the issue is that end time is attached as a statement qualifier, in particular to the statement about being a municipality of the Netherlands. I suggest to read a bit about the Wikidata data model, it's a bit different from other RDF databases, but once you understood all its features, it'S very powerful though sometimes complex and cumbersome to query on. Maybe this one gives some insights: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format

Comment: the query would be something like `PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT ?muncipality (MAX(?population) AS ?maxPopulation)
WHERE
{
  ?muncipality p:P31 ?stmt .
  ?stmt ps:P31 wd:Q2039348 .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{?stmt pq:P582 ?endtime}
  
  ?muncipality wdt:P1082 ?population.
 
}
GROUP BY ?muncipality
ORDER BY DESC(?maxPopulation)` - take a note at the different prefixes I used, so instead of `wdt:` we use `p:` to get the statement entity first, with `ps:` we get the value and `pq::` denotes qualifiers

Comment: Aah okay, that was indeed the issue at hand. Thank you very much!